# Syntax error when running SQL command in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax-error

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Max(Date_Time) From Daily_Sale ", con); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
string date_tim = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
MessageBox.Show("date time" + date_tim);
```

This shows date time in a message box, but when I call this query:

```
cmdc = new SqlCommand("Select Total_Sale from Daily_Sale Where Date_Time ="+ date_tim,con);
cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get a syntax error.

`Date_Time` is saved as `nvarchar(50)`.

Comment: can you try `"Select Total_Sale from Daily_Sale Where Date_Time ="+ " ' " + date_tim + " ' ",con` ?

Comment: try like this..cmdc = new SqlCommand("Select Total_Sale from Daily_Sale Where Date_Time =' "+ date_tim+" ' ",con);

Comment: You're advising him to keep concatenating?  Great help you guys are. Ever heard of a prepared statement?

Comment: yes it work but this qury int sale_pre = (int)cmdc.ExecuteScalar(); gives error object reference is not set on an instance of an object. while when i was run they query ("select Totale_Sale from Daily_sale ") it give value

Comment: *Date_Time is saved in nvarchar(50).* Why? This can only cause you problems. Never store datetime as strings. Use DateTime2 instead.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use parameters to send data to SQL. Never concatenate strings of data to SQL statement. That's a security hole as it's an open door to SQL Injection attacks.
For more information, read [How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks) and Microsoft Docs - [How to: Perform Parameterized Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries)

Second, Never store dates as strings in your database. For date only values, use the `Date` data type. For time only values, use the `Time` data type. For date and time values, use the `DateTime2` data type ([why not use `DateTime`?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)).
For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493836/convert-01-sep-2017-to-01-09-2017-in-t-sql/49494562#49494562) on SO to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493836/convert-01-sep-2017-to-01-09-2017-in-t-sql)

Third, you don't need two queries to get the last value of total_sale from the database. You can do that in a single query, without any parameters at all:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Total_Sale
FROM Daily_Sale 
ORDER BY Date_Time DESC
```

If you want the date time value as well, simply add that to the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Total_Sale, Date_Time 
FROM Daily_Sale 
ORDER BY Date_Time DESC
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Zohar Peled . you save my lot of time to waste .it's working now .please help and guide me further in future .

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)